# Hyperledger modeling: array with fixed length

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am just getting started with Hyperledger and am trying to create the following asset in the .cto file

```
asset Contract identified by contractId {
  o String contractId
  o Boolean[] services
}
```

where all instances of Contract will have a "services" array with a fixed length of 9 (i.e. it should be impossible for the user to create a contract with any other length.)

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use this regex eg. `String myfield regex=/^[0-9]{9}$/` will make sure it must be 9 digits (if its all digits etc etc).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but maybe I wasn't totally clear. Basically, what I mean is that "services" as an array should always contain exactly 9 booleans, and I'm looking for a way to make that explicit in the code